# No Ip Address Connecting Docker Toolbox - Mac OX High Sierra

Tags: macos, docker, docker-toolbox

I want to download the Docker Toolbox on my 2017 Macbook Pro with High Sierra. I went to the Docker Toolbox website and downloaded it. I then ran the docker quick install terminal from the installer and then it started running and getting docker and the vm machine on my Macbook Pro. I then notices that it was throwing an error and not giving me an ip address to access the webpage. There was an error with connecting to a vm:

```
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...
(default) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(default) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(default) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
(default) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(default) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(default) 
(default) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running



                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/


Error getting IP address: Host is not running
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
```

I tried to run

```
docker run hello-world
```

to test it and got another error.

```
omars-mbp:~ omarjandali$ docker run -d hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Does anyone know what is going on or what I need to do to get docker to run on my Macbook Pro 2017.

Comment: what's `env | grep DOCKER` returning? Btw, why not using the Docker for Mac? You'll skip this whole nightmare with VirtualBox

Comment: is that different than the docker toolbox for mac... @Stefano

Comment: yep, completely as it's a native implementation.  no more pain with  virtualbox